# Selecting all options from a list and comparing them against another list

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium and Python to create some automated tests. Currently I am trying to get all of the options from a select list and verify they match another list. I am not sure how to go about grabbing all the options and putting them in a format that I can cross reference with my master list.

I have been poking around using Select commands but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. Below is the sample list i want to get the options from.

```
<select size="5" id="jobSelect" name="jobSelect" class="jobDropDown">                     
<option value="841444562">Bartender Job&nbsp;</option>                     
<option value="841444563">Line Cook Job&nbsp;</option>                     
<option value="841444559">Server Job&nbsp;</option>                     
<option value="913367599">test job&nbsp;</option>             
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all of the options in the select:

```
options = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("jobSelect")).options
```

Then use cmp(options, otherList) as suggested by MONTYHS

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't want the option itself because they are web elements and you would be comparing two lists of web elements I've never compared web elements, because like web elements are in different places in the DOM ane if you had two exact lists on the same page the list comparison would fail because the web elements in options 1 list are different from the web elements in options 2 list.

```
options = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("jobSelect")).options
```

returns list of web elements. Maybe that is what you want but more likely you want the text or value. In that case you need to loop over the web_elements and get the text or value.

```
for option in options:
    print(option.text)
    print(option.get_attribute('value'))
```

Put the text or values in a list and compare as stated in the other post.

Answer (score -1):

no idea if this is an efficient way to do it but you could try

```
for i in lista: 
    if i in listb: 
      print("found: " + i)
```